# Looping through an object where sub-object names are unknown

Tags: php, object, loops, foreach

I have a PHP object which looks something like this:

```
ObjectName:
  W1:
    D1
    D2
    D3
  W2:
    D1
    D2
    D3
    D4
    D5
  W4:
    D1
    D2
    D3
    D4
```

I want to iterate through the `W#`s, and within them the `D#`s. Using:

```
foreach ($theObject as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key, $value";
}
```

gives me:

`ObjectName,`.

Using: 
    foreach ($theObject->ObjectName as $key => $value) {
      echo "$key, $value";
    }
outputs nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values that you are looping through are [visible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), something along the lines of the following should work:

```
foreach ($theObject as $key => $value) {
 foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
  echo "$k, $v";
 }
}
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to look at the [Iterator interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) to better control what happens when you loop through your object.